# 1099-MISC and state file taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, form-1099-misc

I received 1099-misc for a work from home part-time job for $6,500. No state taxes were withheld. I'm located in Maryland and the employer is in Connecticut. Am I supposed to file state taxes for Connecticut?

Comment: You did all of the work _in_ Maryland?

Comment: Yes. I worked from my home in Maryland and was never in Connecticut.